# How to that prove this using induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to prove that using induction:

Considering n $\in \mathbb N*$ and $x, y, \alpha_1, \alpha_2,...,\alpha_n, \beta_1, \beta_2,..., \beta_n$ real numbers then

$2xy(\alpha_1\beta_1 + \alpha_2\beta_2 + ... + \alpha_n\beta_n) \le x^2(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + ... + \alpha_n^2) + y^2(\beta_1^2 + \beta_1^2 + ... + \beta_n^2)$

---

That's what I thought to do:

$2xy(\alpha_1\beta_1 + \alpha_2\beta_2 + ... + \alpha_n\beta_n) \le x^2(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + ... + \alpha_n^2) + y^2(\beta_1^2 + \beta_1^2 + ... + \beta_n^2) \equiv \sum_{i=1}^n (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2 \ge 0$

Using the expression found:

Base case(1) : $\sum_{i=1}^n (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2  = (x\alpha_1 - y\beta_1)^2 \ge 0$

Induction Step:

Assuming $\sum_{i=1}^k (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2  \ge 0$ true, then we have to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2 \ge 0$.

$\sum_{i=1}^k (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2  \ge 0$

$\sum_{i=1}^k (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2 + (x\alpha_{k+1} - y\beta_{k+1})^2 \ge (x\alpha_{k+1} - y\beta_{k+1})^2$

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2 \ge (x\alpha_{k+1} - y\beta_{k+1})^2$

But,

$(x\alpha_{k+1} - y\beta_{k+1})^2 \ge 0$

Therefore,

$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} (x\alpha_i - y\beta_i)^2 \ge 0$

Did I something wrong?

Comment: More of that induction nonsense.  This can be proven directly term by term with half as much effort.

Comment: The first equivalence is not very clear

Comment: @WilliamElliot I have to use induction

Comment: @DiegoAsterio I just did some algebraic manipulation, nothing special. I subtracted  2xy(α1β1+α2β2+...+αnβn) on both sides, used distributive property and applied notable products.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, perhaps instead of assuming the base case you could simply prove it for $k=1$

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you write an equivalent form "sum of squares is nonnegative". That is obviously true so the proof can end there. Why bother with all the rest?

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but I must prove using induction.